# Why does CMake not find GTest (Google Test)?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

There is a ready project. In one of the cmake-files there is a source code:

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
if (NOT GTest_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find Google Test Framework!")
endif()
```

Gives an error: "Cannot find Google Test Framework!"

How to fix error?

Comment: Where is GTest installed on your system? Add this information into the question post, because questions like "cannot find a package" are useless without notion that you actually have the package.

Comment: This depends on your platform, too. Windows and Mac may require  different setups.

Answer (score 1):

While CMake provides a [`FindGTest.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGTest.cmake) module since 2009...

I prefer to incorporate googletest in your CMake project like explaining in the googletest documentation.
https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project

Note: a more detailed explanation http://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/

Comment: cmake provides this FindGTest.cmake file: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGTest.cmake

Answer (score 1):

The `FindGTest.cmake` file uses the environment variable `GTEST_ROOT`. 
You can add this variable to your system or just add it to your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(GTEST_ROOT "c:/path/to/gtest/root" CACHE PATH "path to gtest").
```

This should solve your problem. It is of course possible to completely add gtest to a project (like Luis Miglietti suggested), but thats maybe not what you want to do as a first try.

Comment: But now you raise the fun problem of what does "c:/path/to/gtest/root" actually correspond to and not just on Linux but on the other OSs where cmake wants to play.

Comment: You are saying it! There are many OS and ways of installation. So this could be a each time a new question. The short answer: Clone the repo (https://github.com/google/googletest) into a folder of your choice and build it within this new folder. Then GTEST_ROOT should point to this. Are you okay with that?

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful for you so you don't have to depend on a local google test install, this should work independently if you have google test installed in your machine

You can add this to your cmake file (you should take care of the proper linking / include depending on your project structure)

This will download google test, configure the installation and build it in **vendor/gtm/gtest** (you could always change this) inside your main build folder.  Then you can link **gtest** to an executable so you can run your tests from there

```
include(ExternalProject)
find_package(Git REQUIRED)

# Build googletest
ExternalProject_Add(
    googletest
    PREFIX "vendor/gtm"
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/google/googletest.git"
    GIT_TAG release-1.8.0
    TIMEOUT 10
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
)

# Build gtest
ExternalProject_Add(
    gtest_src
    PREFIX "vendor/gtm"
    SOURCE_DIR "vendor/gtm/src/googletest/googletest"
    INSTALL_DIR "vendor/gtm/gtest"
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vendor/gtm/gtest
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
)

# Prepare gtest
ExternalProject_Get_Property(gtest_src install_dir)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR ${install_dir}/include)
set(GTEST_LIBRARY_PATH ${install_dir}/lib/libgtest.a)
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_library(gtest STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET gtest PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION  ${GTEST_LIBRARY_PATH})
set_property(TARGET gtest APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_dependencies(gtest_src googletest)
add_dependencies(gtest gtest_src)
```

Then you can link **gtest** to an executable with something like

```
add_executable(tester test/tester.cc)
target_link_libraries(tester gtest)
enable_testing()
add_test(<library> tester)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Care to explain a bit what the script does? Code only answers are regarded as low quality.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Why don't simply point to https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project